# scipy.io save/load Matlab file performance

Tags: performance, file, numpy, scipy, save

Many questions here have been asked about the numpy save/load performance, particularly in comparison to alternatives like pickling or using hdf5. In the context of exploratory scientific computing, my issue is that it's difficult to save/load arbitrary combinations of objects in my workspace, e.g. if I have a string, a float, a (large) numpy array, and a struct. The best way I see to save all of these seems to be to create several files, e.g. a .npz for the arrays and a .pkl for the rest. I would like to save all of them into one file. Matlab provides this functionality very easily with their .mat file format. It turns out that scipy can [save/load .mat files](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/io.html#matlab-files) as well.

I'm wondering, how does the `scipy.io.loadmat()` and `savemat()` functions compare in performance to Matlab? To pickling/numpy.save/hdf5?

Alternatively, is there a better way to save arbitrary collections of objects into one file?

Comment: How are you going to measure performance?  I've answered a lot of questions about these save/load methods, but always with the focus on 'how to do it', not on what takes more/less time for very large files.  It may be hard to generalize the large file cases.

Comment: I can't think of a better way than to simply generate a set of objects, and measure the time to save and load them. e.g. take a random 1000x1000 np.array, a string, and an object with 5 different np.float64 fields and save them with `scipy.io.savemat()`, and then generate a 1000x1000 matrix in Matlab, along with a string variable and a struct, and `save()` it in Matlab. Time both using Python's/Matlab's respective timing libraries.

Comment: The `scipy` version of load/savemat probably isn't as fast as the MATLAB version - not without those big commerical bucks behind it.  It may be competitive with Octave's.  `np.save/load` should be pretty good since it just saves a small header block followed by a byte copy of the array's databuffer.  `h5py` uses the compiled `HDF5` backend for actual saving, and cython code for most of the interfacing.